# Падает apache 2.2 на FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, apache2

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема на сервере, по непонятным причинам стал падать apache, причем он просто зависает в процессах, приходится убивать и запускать заново, но это помогает максимум на час. Как выяснить, в чем кроется причина?

UPD 17.09.2015: Сейчас сервер стал просто дико виснуть, сайты соот-но тоже. В логах апачи последние 50 строк:

```
(32)Broken pipe: core_output_filter: writing data to the network
```

Для того, чтобы эта строка ушла, нашел, что необходимо прописать EnableSendfile off. Дальше буду мониторить, помогло это или нет.

Comment: Давайте начнем с логов... Приведите последних строк 100 (access и error)

Comment: автор! проблема актуальна? мои 5 копеек - не исчерпана ли свободная память на сервере в момент падений?

Comment: Скажем так, проблема сейчас почти не возникает, + есть более первоочередные задачи, поэтому я пока эти вопросом детально не занимался, но тема для меня еще актуальна, так как причины такого поведения я не выяснил.

Comment: Это ошибка означает что кто-то или что-то ложит сервис, надо бы побольше кусок лога

Comment: Выход - поставить nginx ) возможно  slowloris